# How to solve Django Rest Api Deployment 404 Error on Vercel

Tags: python, django, deployment, vercel

I tried to deployed my django rest api project on vercel and it shows the message deployment successfully.

But i open the visit it shows an error

```
404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND
ID: bom1::d724b-1688197940778-5b5d73a1c7a7
```

i dont know how to fix this error im using the vercel deployment on first time. There is any solution to fix this error

vercel

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
    {
    "src": "devntechno/wsgi.py",
    "use": "@vercel/python",
    "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9" }
    },
    {
    "src": "build_files.sh",
    "use": "@vercel/static-build",
    "config": {
    "distDir": "staticfiles_build"
     }
    }
    ],
    "routes": [
    {
    "src": "/static/(.*)",
    "dest": "/static/$1"
    },
    {
    "src": "/(.*)",
    "dest": "devntechno/wsgi.py"
    }
    ]
    }
```

This is my vercel code and after that i changed to

```
{
    "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }]
}
```

But again shos the same error

settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.vercel.app', '.now.sh']

STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles_build', 'static')
```

Answer (score 1):

i had huge battle with that. and won :) my **vercel.json** looks like that:

```
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "build_files.sh",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": {
        "distDir": "staticfiles_build"
      }
    },
    {
      "src": "/czarny_kot/wsgi.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python",
      "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb" }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "czarny_kot/wsgi.py"
    },
    {
      "src": "/static/(.*)",
      "dest": "/static/$1"
    }
  ]
}
```

my **build_file.sh** has only two lines:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
python3.9 manage.py collectstatic
```

I added on the bottom in **wsgi.py** one line:

```
app = application
```

in **settings.py** (instead od changes in ALLOWED_HOSTS and STATIC stuff) i changed WSGI_APPLICATION:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'czarny_kot.wsgi.app'
```

i changed as well DATABASES:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": env("POSTGRES_DATABASE"),
        "USER": env('POSTGRES_USER'),
        "PASSWORD": env('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        "HOST": env("POSTGRES_HOST"),
        "URL": env("POSTGRES_URL"),
        "PORT": "5432"
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        # 'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

of course i made migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

all this stuff works only if project tree looks on vercel like that:

[image]

on github is similar:

[image: structure from vercel]

it's possible tha u have different structure like:

[image]

so if u have one more directory above Django apps u need to choose custom root directory:

[image: root directory choosing]

choose the directory just above django apps - second one. hope it will resolve your problem.